# How does the following javascript statement evaluate?

Tags: javascript

The following statement does not have an `if` statement, even though it uses the `?` character. How does it evaluate?

`var username = req.user ? req.user.username : '';`

Comment: It's the [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), also known as the ternary operator. I know it's hard to google individual operators like `?`, but it is easy to google "javascript operators"...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's equivalent to this:

```
var username;

if (req.user) {
    username = req.user.username;
} else {
    username = '';
}
```

[Read more about **ternary operators** on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).